# API Spring boot auto redirect to login page

Tags: java, spring, api, spring-boot

I'm trying to integrate spring security with spring boot restful API. my project's code as follows:

web security configurations are

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/API/**");
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/API/user/**").permitAll()
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");

    }
}
```

UserController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/API/user")
public class UserRestApiController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/all", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<Users>> getAll(){
        return new ResponseEntity<Collection<Users>>(userService.getAlluser(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Users> getUser(@PathVariable(value="id") int id){
        return new ResponseEntity<Users>(userService.getUser(id), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/delete/{id}", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
    public String deleteUser(@PathVariable(value="id")int id){
        userService.deleteUser(id);
        return "DELETED";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/create", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> addUser(@Valid @RequestBody Users user){
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(userService.addUser(user), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/update", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> updateUser(@Valid @RequestBody Users user){
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(userService.updateUser(user), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

UserService:

```
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public Collection<Users> getAlluser() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Users getUser(int id) {
        return userRepository.getOne(id);
    }

    public void deleteUser(int id) {
        userRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    public Users updateUser(Users user) {
        //Users u = userRepository.getOne(user.getId());
        Users userUpdate = null;
        if(userRepository.findById(user.getId()) != null) {
             userUpdate = userRepository.save(user);
        }
        return userUpdate;
    }

    public String addUser(Users user) {
        Users tmpUser = userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername());
        if(tmpUser == null) {
            userRepository.save(user);
            return "CREATED";
        } else {
            return "EXISTED";
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying build restful API. and when I try access link like: http://localhost:8080/API/user/all

instead return  json value, it redirect to login page(I don't config do that).

image login page: [login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6fjA.png)

Can you help me clear this case ?

Answer (score 5):

Another way, If you want to bypass that form without removing the spring-security dependencies. You can provide username/password like this:

a) username is user

b) password is a hash string that you can grap on console. For example, it will be located in the line "Using default security password: 3322e14e-b18c-42f2-a399-e391bd9909c4"

Answer (score 3):

Unlike the Spring MVC, the REST service is not supposed to redirect the user to the login page because it is a resource, not a view resolver.
Instead, the caller (web browser as an example) redirects the user to the login page when it receives HTTP code 401.

Comment: Currently, I have resolved this issue. look like by default, when I add dependency `spring-boot-starter-security` it will auto redirect to login page. I must be delete dependency or config for login.

Comment: @VuVuong Keep in mind it is a bad practice for a REST to return a login page.  Because you are breaking the response uniformity and mixing API  responsibilities. REST should return the desired content not to handle the authentication or security redirect. You can read more from this link https://restfulapi.net/